# Count specific characters from column associated with dual categories of other column. Do it iteratively based on frequency bins

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply

I have a huge dataframe df1, whose oversimplified version consists of 3 columns, "Words", "Frequency" and "Letters":

```
Words           Frequency   Letters
flower/tree     0.15        a(0.1)
tree            0.67        a(0.4)
planet          0.85        b(0.4)
tree/planet     0.42        c(0.5)
tree            0.89        a(0.6)
flower          0.21        b(0.4)
flower/planet   0.53        b
planet          0.07        a
```

Using R (dplyr, apply family functions, etc.) I would like to count the number of times every letter (a, b, c) of the "Letter" column is associated with every single word from the "Word" column (flower, tree, planet), in an iterative way dependent on the frequency bin of the "Frequency" column values. There are 4 bins: [0, 0.25], [0.25, 0.5], [0.5, 0.75], [0.75, 1].

I expect an output dataframe df2 that looks something like this:

```
Bin       Word    Letters    count_letters
0-0.25    flower  a          1
0-0.25    flower  b          1
0-0.25    tree    a          1
0-0.25    planet  a          1
0.25-0.5  tree    c          1
0.25-0.5  planet  c          1
0.5-0.75  flower  b          1
0.5-0.75  tree    a          1
0.5-0.75  planet  b          1
0.75-1    tree    a          1
0.75-1    planet  b          1
```

Comment: What are the numbers in parentheses after the letters?

Comment: @Lucas his question was about the parentheses not the letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cut` to bin `Frequency`, `substr` to clean `Letters`, and `tidyr::separate_rows` to unnest `Word`. Aggregate with `dplyr::count`, and you're set:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% separate_rows(Words) %>% 
    count(Words, 
          Letters = substr(Letters, 1, 1),    # use regex if more than one letter
          Frequency = cut(Frequency, breaks = seq(0, 1, .25)))

## Source: local data frame [11 x 4]
## Groups: Frequency, Words [?]
## 
##     Frequency  Words Letters     n
##        <fctr>  <chr>   <chr> <int>
## 1    (0,0.25] flower       a     1
## 2    (0,0.25] flower       b     1
## 3    (0,0.25] planet       a     1
## 4    (0,0.25]   tree       a     1
## 5  (0.25,0.5] planet       c     1
## 6  (0.25,0.5]   tree       c     1
## 7  (0.5,0.75] flower       b     1
## 8  (0.5,0.75] planet       b     1
## 9  (0.5,0.75]   tree       a     1
## 10   (0.75,1] planet       b     1
## 11   (0.75,1]   tree       a     1
```